# Transaction tables storing extra datas for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have relational db. problem. I have two tables and 1 transaction table for them. For example 'User' table, 'book' table and 'txUserReadingBooks' table. If i put only UserId and BookId in tx table, there is no problem. But if i want to store reading duration in this table, this tx table is not a tx table anymore. How can i store these datas or as an another question is it right to store these datas like this?

Why i am asking this question; i will release asp.net web api over that database. I disabled lazyloading because of infinite loops so i will do anything with 'include' key.

I am on the right track? Waiting for your suggestions.

Sorry for my English, Thanks,

Comment: There nothing intrinsickly wrong with having other fields in your connecting table.

Comment: but when you add these datas, EF takes this table as a real table. Actually it becames a data table too, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does, but why is that a problem if want data to be associated with act of a user reading a book.  Personally i think it is better to do it this way otherwise you end up with an awkward 1 to 1 relationship with a fourth table.

Comment: Then i should add autoinc primaryKey in tx table for 1 to 1. That is also a problem for tx table. I thing i will keep doing this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct - you typically don't want to store calculated data in your transaction tables.  If all of the calculations depend on other data *in the same record* it's tolerable, but definitely avoid fields that depend on data in other records.

The cleanest solution is to create a view or stored procedure to calculate reading duration.

Comment: But its not just reading durating. For example i want to sell book, and store having date. In that way there will be a txUserBooks table and i need to store havingDate.. for something like reports ect.